# How to include the generation of html files from raml files during the building of a maven project

Tags: rest, maven, building, raml, exec-maven-plugin

I am working on a Java REST application, and I have raml files that document the API of the endpoints. The application is built using maven.

Until now we have been manually generating html files from the raml files, but we would like to incorporate the generation of html files from the raml files in the build process (so that it happens automatically each time the application is built, and avoid the possibility that we build a version in which the code does not match the html files).

Currently we have the complication that some of the raml files are 0.8 and some are 1.0, but it would not be a huge effort to bring them all to 1.0.

Its not possible to know exactly the characteristics of the machine where the building will happen (it could be Linux (Ubuntu or CentOS) or Windows 10), and we don't want to assume that any utilities will already be installed on the machine where the building will happen. For example, we don't want to assume that raml2html will be installed on the machine where the building will happen.

**My question is: what is the best/simplest way of including the generation of html files from raml files in the build process of a maven project**

I was thinking that one way is to include raml2html as a dependency in the maven pom file, and invoke that tool (possibly using a maven plugin) during the building. But all the guides related to raml2html that I have seen seem to require that raml2html must be installed on the machine. Such as this one: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/generating-html-documentation-from-raml-documents-with-maven/

I would prefer not to add this requirement to the build process. I would like anyone to be able to compile the project "out of the box" (assuming of course that they have maven, java, etc. installed).

Versions I am using:

- My OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (build the solution should also work on windows
  10):
- java version "1.8.0_121"
- Apache Maven 3.3.9
- npm 3.5.2
- node: v4.2.6

Comment: I think this [plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installing-node-and-npm) lets you run npm install for `raml2html` if not already there.

Comment: ok, thanks. Based on the documentation of that plugin, it seems to provide a way of installing node and npm that are independent of any existing versions that might exist on the computer (ie. they are local to the compilation). So I guess the "-g" should not be used when trying to install raml2html. I have tried to use the plugin, and it does indeed seem to install node, npm and raml2html, but its fails in the exec-maven-plugin where I try to run raml2html. Its giving Command execution failed. Cannot run program "raml2html"". Looks like the command raml2html is not recognized at that moment.

Comment: It can happen when the raml2html is not available in the `Path`. But having running inside the maven plugin, did you try different configuration options like `<environmentVariables>` and `<installDirectory>target</installDirectory>`.

Comment: Hi, its working now. As you thought, my problem was a paths issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share your final solution?